# Where can I find meta-alloys without taking a risky fight?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

I've re-installed Elite and after logging in, halfway to Saggitarius I decided to head back and check out the new content.

This lead me to the Engineers and I need one meta-alloy to get this storyline/ questline going.

Now according to various forums posts and [spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bichQJBbL9ygW1xXc3GQhC5KT-o9u05ihWKXebt4BcM/edit?pre#gid=0), there should be enough to farm around. My problem is, that after a dozen or so locations I've checked with my cobra MK III, everything is empty.

Merope 5C is one of those unguarded spots, but most of the others are guarded by some mean looking imperial ships. I managed to sneak around some of them (they are after all a good indicator, that I'm in the right region) just to find some empty barnacles again. I'd rather avoid getting in a fight with them. I'm pretty sure my Cobra is not up to the task with its puny little lasers.

So how do I go about at least getting 1(!) meta-alloy to continue on. Is the respawn timer known for those things? Is there one? I've been switching between private and public every so often. I even jumped into hyperspace and landed again. Nothing did help.

**Update**
Although, this doesn't answer the question, I finally found one at `Pleiades sector IH-V C2-16 D 2  Lat: -1.7955    Lon: 141.2449`. This one was watched by 3 small drones, which my board weapons took care of. Well worth the 2.5k bounty.

Comment: I think at this point the question probably needs to just be "Where can I find meta-alloys, and how often do they respawn?". Given that they're so rare, I don't think you'll really benefit by being choosy over sites that are guarded or not. (Note: I haven't gotten around to hunting for these yet myself, so I'm definitely interested in seeing where this goes.)

Comment: You can always just go to Darnielle's Progress and buy them. Current allocation is 11 and refreshes after 10 minutes. I bought several hundred this last weekend.

Comment: I couldn't find any of them there. Double and triple checked multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You need a large Barnacle Forest. Not small ones.

**Places:** There is a [list of known places with barnacles](http://elitedangerous.hozbase.co.uk/customtable/view/barnacles). Pick any with the largest "No. of Meta Alloys" and go there. I'm sure it's not the only place when you can find a fresh "list of known large barnacle forests".

**Fight:** There might be a thargoid drones. They are not very dangerous and can be taken down just as easily as regular human-made drones. They might ignore you as well.

**Tools:** Don't forget to take SRV, Surface Scanner, and Fuel Scoop.

**Important:** if you see a huge creepy Thargoid ship flying around - don't try to attack it and it won't attack you.

Fly safe CMDR! o7

Answer (score 0):

According to EDDB (https://eddb.io/commodity/114), you can buy them from the Darnielle's Progress port in the Maia system.